# Springboot - SLF4J - logging pattern

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, slf4j

I am facing a hard time finding a solution for a problem I am facing which is:

Let's say I have 4 microservices (A,B,C,D) that interact with each other (rest APIs)

A calls B and B calls D. So that path for a single request is A/B/D

Below is the logging pattern.
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } [%15.15t] %logger{10}:%L | %m%n

I want to add path in it.

So lets say Request is initiated from A to B, in the logs of B I want it to display Path:A/
now B calls D, the Path should be in the logs of D: A/B

Please suggest how do I manage this.

I am sorry for naïve question since I am new to SLF4J

Comment: As far as I understand, you're using the wrong tool. Logging is not tracing. 
To check call flows, try Jaeger.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to know the path your request took!!! for that you can use **Spring Cloud Sleuth** provides Spring Boot auto-configuration for distributed tracing

[image: Example]https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/26/spring-cloud-sleuth